# Adding simulated annealing to a simple hill climbing

Tags: artificial-intelligence, simulated-annealing, hill-climbing

I've created a hill climbing algorithm which randomly generates a solution then copies that solution and mutates it a little to see if it ends up with a better solution. If it does it keeps the new solution and discards the old one.

If I want to add simulated annealing to this algorithm could I just start off with a higher mutation rate and decrease the mutation rate a little each time a new solution is created?

I assume then the mutation rate would act as the simulated annealing algorithm's temperature, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. But you should also think about accepting worsening steps sometimes to be able to escape local minima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutation rate would act as a temperature for the annealing but by just chosing the better solution *everytime* wont be a perfect Simulated Annealing.

You need to select the better choice depending on *how much better it is* and the *mutation rate*. (i.e. the deltaE and Temperature) so that you allow Simulated Annealing to get out of local optima. If you keep taking the best choice you might get stuck in a local optimum.

Comment: Singular optimum, plural optima. No such thing as local optimas.